# Common joins of few tables

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-server-2008-r2

We have couple of tables, most of our queries use just a few joins, so in other words, we have something like 2-3 joins that almost every query uses. What are the most common ways how to speed-up this common joins if the tables are getting bigger? We would like to use SQL Server or Oracle.

Comment: Wait, you have a couple of queries in "SQL Server or Oracle" that are slow?

Comment: @Aaron Yes, they aren't that fast, why?

Comment: I'm just confused why you have the same queries in Oracle and in SQL Server.

Comment: @Aaron Ah, sorry for the confusion. We are just choosing the right platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common method is indexing, but you don't provide enough information to be more specific.

Here are some scenarios:

(1)  You have a bunch of reference tables connected to a central table, such as a fact table.

In this case, you want to define an autoincrementing primary key on the reference tables.  This functions automatically as an index.

(2) Your queries are highly selective

In this case, you want to focus the index on the fields in the where clauses.  This is especially true when the second table is quite small, so sequential searches are similar to index searches.

(3) Your joined tables really are a performance bottleneck

In this case, you might want to instantiate the result of the join, either as a table or an instantiated view. This could be needed when your join criterion is complex, such as using a data range in the join criterion.

(4) You have other options as well, such as partitioning the data.

Answer (score 2):

1. materialized views - oracle supports these, and they are useful in some cases, esp. when there are many reads as opposed to writes:
   http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96520/mv.htm
2. indicies - analyze/explain the query plans and see if adding an index would help.  Very often you can improve speed by having different indicies for different queries.  You can also provide hints to tell the query parser which index to use for a particular query.
3. denormalization - store some of the data from these tables in the related tables rather than having to join to get it.
4. caching - increase size of query cache, or create caching layer in app.

Answer (score 1):

Some options

- Lay indexes on te column you join on
- Make the indexes so that they *cover* the data you are after
- Denonormalise your data do the joins are not needed <= biggest win
- use indexed views in SQL Server or materialized views in Oracle
- Make sure you provide the query optimizer the best statistics it can get so it uses the optimal join strategy (hash/merge/loop)